# Why になって and not just use an adverb?

Tags: grammar

寝室で血まみれになって倒れている山村さんを発見して110番した。

Can I just say 寝室で血まみれに倒れている山村さんを発見して110番した。

If not, then when should I use になって to describe a verb?

Context:遺体が見つかったのは、10月11日午後2時ごろ。2日続けてアルバイトを欠勤した山村さんを心配した親族の女性らが部屋を訪れ、寝室で血まみれになって倒れている山村さんを発見して110番した。犯行現場は寝室とみられ、それ以外の部屋にも血痕があったという。

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if we were to interpret the modified phrase in your sentence, you would get something like this:

> 血まみれに倒れている
>
>  Falling down bloodied.

Which, in my opinion, doesn't make much sense here. By turning 血まみれ into an adverb, you are modifying the *verb*, as per its name. "Covered in blood" isn't really describing how 山村さん fell, it describes 山村さん themself. The original sentence allows 血まみれ to become a "state of being" by adding になっている to it.

If you were to break down the sentence into separate statements, this is likely what you would get:

> 血まみれになっている山村さん。
>
>  Yamamura-san, who was covered in blood.

> 倒れている山村さん。
>
>  Yamamura-san, who was collapsed.

倒れている and 血まみれになっている have the same functions here. They describe the state that 山村さん is in.

Comment: 「血まみれ**で**倒れている山村さん」ならいいよね。